# Avoiding MySQL explicit declaration in Slick 3.x

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

In Slick 3.x, I use the code below to wrap the fact that the database is MySQL. This allows me to declare `MySQLDriver` just one time in the entire application:

```
package util

import slick.driver.MySQLDriver

trait DbDriver extends MySQLDriver {
  val dbApi = api
}

object DbDriver extends DbDriver
```

Then in the classes that use Slick I import as follows (instead of a database-specific driver):

```
import util.DbDriver.api._
```

Now, I need to catch duplicate insert exceptions. To do that, I use a MySql class:

```
case Success(res) => 
  // insert succeeded, no duplicate exception
case Failure(e: MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) =>
  // duplicate exception
case Failure(e) => 
  // other failures
```

But this forces me to import in every class `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`.
Is there a way to include it in the generic trait declaration `DbDriver`?

This is my attempt (that does *NOT* work):

Declaring:

```
class Duplicate extends        
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
```

And catching with:

```
case Failure(e: Duplicate) => // print something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a type alias:

```
trait DbDriver extends MySQLDriver {
  val dbApi = api
}

object DbDriver extends DbDriver {
  type Duplicate = com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
}
```

Import this type and you can pattern match on it:

```
case Success(res) => 
  // insert succeeded, no duplicate exception
case Failure(e: Duplicate) =>
  // duplicate exception
case Failure(e) => 
  // other failures
```